# Проблема с импортом модели в django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
from .models import *


class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = telLogin
        fields = [
            "telefon", ]
```

и сама модель

```
class telLogin(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    telefon = models.IntegerField()
    password = models.IntegerField()
    confirmation = models.BooleanField()
```

если убрать `model = telLogin`, сервер запускается и ошибку:

> NameError: name 'telLogin' is not defined

Не пойму почему джанго ругается на это присвоение

Comment: `forms` на одном уровне в директории с `models`? Вообще, проблем с импортом не должен быть, проблема только в том, что так крайне не рекомендуется использоваться импорт *, нужно импортировать все отдельно. Так же классы в python принято записывать с большой буквы :)

Comment: Да, они на одном уровне, импорт прописывал так же вручную для каждого(не помогло), за классы спасибо, буду знать.
Пока вернулся к другой проблеме, будет время еще пересмотрю

Answer (score 2):

Убрать из мета нельзя без последствий, показывает какую модель использует для валидации и генерирования формы

```
class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):  # название формы
    class Meta:  # определяем через какую модель и как форма работает
        model = telLogin  # какую модель использует форма для обработки
        fields = ["telefon", ]  # какие поля отображать при создании
```

Если обработка формы идет js скриптом, то часто проще отказаться от встроенных форм, передавать в POST или GET и обрабатывать, все как в php включая самостоятельную проверку данных.